# Should the "unit-of-measure" tag have a broader usage?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-wikis

The [unit-of-measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unit-of-measure) tag is currently

> For questions related to conversion of units.

Should questions about the unit of measure *itself* be considered as relevant questions under this tag?

This question arises while reading [applying math terms to units of measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2726846/290189).  I can't find a relevant tag for this question except [unit-of-measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unit-of-measure).

---

Edit in response to comments:

I've found [another question about the dimension of radian](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2605865/290189).  This is about a property of radian as a measure of angle, rather than the conversion of radian to degree.  It's about a unit of measure, but it doesn't fit into the tag wiki of [unit-of-measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unit-of-measure).

Should the tag wiki be changed as a result?

Comment: With your second example, I think "dimensional analysis" is the more appropriate tag.  How about adding your proposal of what you think the changed wiki for "unit of measure" should be?

Comment: @amWhy I see your point.  It's tagged as ([tag:measure-theory]).  I don't think that's an appropriate tag, but I can't think of a right tag to replace it, so I asked this question.

Comment: I agree that "measure-theory" is not at all appropriate.  How about "dimensional-analysis" for your linked question?  Truth is, that first example is far too unclear and far too broad that I suspect no specific tag is appropriate. dimensional-analysis: "The study of the relationships between physical quantities by identifying their units of measure and fundamental dimensions. It is used to convert from one set of units to others such as from miles per hour to meters per second, or from calories per slice of cake to kilocalories per whole cake."

Comment: So it seems the wiki for unit-of-measure's tag description significantly overlaps with dimensional-analysis's tag description.  I'm sincere if you have any suggestions for the "unit-of-measure" wiki, that differs enough from "dimensional-analysis" to warrant its existence.  Otherwise, perhaps one of the other should become a synonym of the other.

Comment: @amWhy I'm just curious whether there's more math about "unit of measurement" than "conversion of units", say some properties like dimension, etc, of units.  Since a tag wiki is for the use of others, I don't dare to edit it until I come up with a clear example.